# Interactive directed graphs with SVG and Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, visualization, dot, directed-graph

I have to add some interactive features to SVG directed graphs.

So far the graphs I want to show are generated from a dot file and rendered as SVG. I'd like to know if there is some easy way to add interactivity (Maybe with Javascript) to such SVG documents.

What I need is to display some information when the mouse goes over a node and to make it possible to compare two nodes.

Since my models are generated automatically I would prefer to keep the dot-generated SVG and put on it additional information with a separate Javascript.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your DOT generated SVG?

Comment: @kzh Of course. I have to deal with something having nodes and edges such as the one in this gist https://gist.github.com/1223221
I just found canviz is able to deal directly with dot files, do you think it would be easier to add interactivity to a SVG element o to a canviz graph?

Comment: That's good question ... did you figure the best answer ? Actually what I would like to do is reduce/exand graphviz clusters by clicking on them, from the web browser. Any idea ?

Comment: @Stéphane I'm starting a series of post on my blog covering the topic but unfortunately I don't have too much time to write them http://wishlabs.blogspot.com/2011/09/interactive-dot-generated-svg-graph.html
I think my approach is good to add additional information, to manipulate colors and to show/hide nodes and arcs but I don't think it is going to be too effective if you have to change the layout of the graph. For that try a javascript graph visualization library, I guess it is going to serve better your purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have an example with inline SVG. The difference between this SVG and what you have is that the one in my demo has id attributes for nodes and things. I did get this SVG from the graphviz website.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JVbsX/)

(Click on the "Hello" node)

When I get a chance to upload an SVG on my server, I will try accessing SVG from an embed element. I can't do it on JSFiddle do to same domain policy in browsers.

[This page](http://www.schepers.cc/svg/blendups/embedding.html) may also be of help. It shows some of the scripting capabilities of SVG, although for all of the examples, the script is in the SVG itself.

Comment: Thanks, actually I can inline SVG on the web-page so that should be enough.
The main issue is related to the fact that I don't have meaningful id attributes. What would be meaningful for me is the svg:title, is it possible to get the element having a specific title (Maybe with jQuery)?

Comment: It seems I can get SVG with meaningful identifiers: http://www.graphviz.org/content/preservation-dot-id-svg

Comment: Awesome. You should repost in your question with what you came up with and your process. I'd be interested to see.

Comment: Sure, as soon as I come up with something working I'll keep you up to date. I was planning to do it on the weekend but I didn't managed to do it :)